node app zip file upload not including .next(production)dir when uploading to Azure WebApp
I'm experiencing an issue while deploying my Node.js web application to an Azure Web App using the zip deploy method, which is the only deployment option allowed by my organization's policies.
Here's the situation:
I cannot deploy the app using the Azure VScode extension.
My application requires running npm run build to generate the production build, which creates a .next directory.
Despite this, every time I deploy the build via zip deploy, the .next directory does not get included in the web app's file system.
This missing .next directory is critical as it contains the default document for my application. Could you assist in resolving why this directory is not being deployed and suggest how I can ensure it is included or how can I work around this issue. TIA
I tried compressing and uploading the project after I ran "npm build run" however, the .next dir does not make it to azure

If possible, share your repository or code?

Did you open the zip before upload and verify .next was in there? Also, have you checked that your app is configured to use the node.js runtime, and not anything else, such as .NET?

@ArchitectJamie yes, I did. I was just recently able to upload the .next dir using the diagnostic console (Kudu Plus) however I still get the same error, which is that the default document that is in the root dir(index,html) is now live, but when I click any of the links in there, it breaks.

What error do you get?

the error i get is "the resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable"

@Johnny Cheng Are you deploying your app to Azure web app Linux or Azure web app Windows?

@Johnny Cheng Are you importing packages using import method? It does not work in Windows web app. You need to use require. type as CommonJS not module in package.json

@AsleshaKantamsetti it is to a Windows azure web app.

@AsleshaKantamsetti yes I was using import method. I will try what u suggested. Thank you

@AsleshaKantamsetti also did u have to place the default document "index.html" in the root dir? Azure docs are telling me to do that

@Johnny Cheng I didn't place any default document "index.html".  in the root directory. Check my solution once.

@Johnny Cheng I added the web.config and server.js file to the root directory of the project.

I Created Simple nextjs App using below command:
npx create-next-app@latest <AppName>
Run and build the application using npm run dev and npm run build.
Local Output:


When I Zip the Nextjs app even I didn't find .next file in folder, so I selected the file I want to Zip from Main project folder as shown below.


Now I able to see the .next file in the Zip Folder as shown below.

For deploying nextjs app to Azure Web App Windows you need web.config and server.js.
Thanks to @Parveen, for Clearly explanation.
Below is web.config and server.js files.
web.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
       <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

server.js:
const { createServer } = require("http");
const next = require("next");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    handle(req, res);
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});

By using below command, I deployed the Zip folder to Azure web App.
az webapp deploy --resource-group <rg-name> --name <app-name> --src-path <zip-package-path>

I successfully deployed the nextjs app.

Azure Web App Output:


@Johnny Cheng Please check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with
